# Multiple Remote KVM Computers

Tags: networking, kvm, remote-desktop

I want to ask if it is possible to have multiple (3-6) Windows Virtual machines on a Unix Server system. The Windows VMs should communicate with each other over the network and every VM should be reachable with Remote Desktop that the users could work together at the same time.

- Is that possible with KVM
- Is there any hardware prerequisites
- Is every VM reachable over the Network by IP (because the server have only two network cards but 6 VMs)

Thanks for your input

Answer (score 0):

yes.

network cards don't care about ip in general (high end ones may have technology to calculate things like tcp checksums).

You can have more than 1 VM running at a time.